# Replace values in associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm consuming an API which returns an array of objects as this:

```
$base = array(
    ["orange","_","banana"], 
    ["banana","_","_"], 
    ["_","apple","kiwi"], 
    ["_","raspberry","strawberry"]
);
```

And I intend to show "0" when key value is "_" however I haven't found a better way to do this than this:

```
foreach ($base as $key => $value) {
    for ($i=0; $i<=3;$i++) {
        if ($base[$key][$i]=="_")
            $base[$key][$i]="0";
    }
}
```

This works just fine since it's a simple demo but the real array is sometimes big and I've found this solution somewhat inefficient.

My question is, there's some php built-in function to do achieve this in or at least a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance guys,

Comment: That's not an associative array. That's an indexed arrays that contains other indexed arrays (multidimensional array). So when you say: _when key value is "\_"_, it doesn't really make sense, since all keys in your arrays are numeric.

Answer (score 2):

Use `array_walk_recursive()`, pass the elements by reference and walk over the array, checking for the value `_` - if its a match, replace it with `0`.

```php
$base = array(
    ["orange","_","banana"], 
    ["banana","_","_"], 
    ["_","apple","kiwi"], 
    ["_","raspberry","strawberry"]
);

array_walk_recursive($base, function(&$v) {
    if ($v === '_')
        $v = 0;
});
```

Output becomes

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => orange
            [1] => 0
            [2] => banana
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => banana
            [1] => 0
            [2] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => apple
            [2] => kiwi
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => raspberry
            [2] => strawberry
        )

)
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/6Bs8ZE

Comment: Holy smokes...array_walk_recursive where have you been all of my life! Neat and works like a charm! Thank you very much Qirel

Answer (score 2):

You can replace `_` with `0`;

```
json_decode(str_replace('"_"','"0"',json_encode($base)));
```

Comment: This seemed like a great solution and made a lot of sense to me but didn't work :(

Comment: Your answer was correct, sorry. My mistake is that I didn't realized until now that I also needed a solution to replace not only "_" but  "". Hence I had to use the other variant involving walk the array entirely. Thank you for you help Kris.